# How to set target pose in MoveIt?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any GUI tool to set planning group's start state or goal state in MoveIt? We now can use API and interactive marker to control the arm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200108/how-to-set-target-pose-in-moveit-?/) by [frog0705](https://answers.ros.org/users/2462/frog0705/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Would the [RViz MoveIt plugin](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/moveit_ros_visualization/html/doc/tutorial.html) work for your use case?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frog0705](https://answers.ros.org/users/2462/frog0705/) on 2014-12-28**:
Yeah, that's good,but I want to display the end-effector's pose in real-time in RViz during dragging the interactive marker. Perhaps, MoveIt already has the function, I should learn more about it. Thank you.